# Check if the result is included in a command answer

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a command only if the command answer does't include: X-UA-Compatible

So I have tried this:

```
set APPCMD_EXEC=c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%APPCMD_EXEC% list config "Default Web site" /section:httpProtocol /text:*') do @set VALUE_1=%%a

IF %VALUE_1% EQU [] Echo List Empty
IF %VALUE_1% NEQ [] Echo %VALUE_1%


REM %APPCMD_EXEC% set config "Default Web site" /section:system.webserver/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='X-UA-Compatible',value='IE=EmulateIE9']"
```

The answer I get is

```
[redirectHeaders]
```

but if i run only the command I get all this:

```
CONFIG
 CONFIG.SECTION:"system.webServer/h
 path:"MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Defa
 overrideMode:"Inherit"
 locked:"false"
[system.webServer/httpProtocol]
allowKeepAlive:"true"
[customHeaders]
  [add]
    name:"X-UA-Compatible"
    value:"IE=EmulateIE9"
[redirectHeaders]
```

So how can I do this so I can find if the X-UA-Compatible exist in my command answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
@echo off

c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config "Default Web site" /section:httpProtocol /text:* | find "X-UA-Compatible" && goto:found || echo not found
exit /b

:found
echo Here the command to execute
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only set `value_1` if the term `X-UA-Compatible` is not found.  The `find` filter in the for loop helps there.

```
set APPCMD_EXEC=c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe

set "value_1="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%APPCMD_EXEC% list config "Default Web site" /section:httpProtocol /text:* ^| find /v "X-UA-Compatible" ') do @set "VALUE_1=%%a"

if not defined VALUE_1 Echo List Empty
if defined VALUE_1 Echo %VALUE_1%


REM %APPCMD_EXEC% set config "Default Web site" /section:system.webserver/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='X-UA-Compatible',value='IE=EmulateIE9']"
```

So you can do this to execute the command in your example only if the term is not found:

```
set APPCMD_EXEC=c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%APPCMD_EXEC% list config "Default Web site" /section:httpProtocol /text:* ^| find /v "X-UA-Compatible" ') do %APPCMD_EXEC% set config "Default Web site" /section:system.webserver/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='X-UA-Compatible',value='IE=EmulateIE9']"
```